# Hibernate AnnotationException Thrown when SessionFactory is Created

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am having a problem with hibernate. I am updating a previously created database created in Oracle SQL in order to get some practice with hibernate. The thing is that I am getting an AnnotationException that one class object is trying to reference something from the other class. Here is the error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.revature.bank.POJO.BankAccount.customer references an unknown entity: com.revature.bank.POJO.Customer
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:107)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1580)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1503)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1419)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1856)
at com.revature.bank.POJO.DataFuncImp.createCustomer(DataFuncImp.java:16)
at com.revature.bank.POJO.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

So, this is pointing to the line:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

I have read that it might be happening because the annotations but none of the previously asked questions here seemed to work. 
Here are my two classes: (i will only put the variables as that's where the error points to):
Customer.java

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="USER_TABLE")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int user_id;
@Column
private String user_fname;
@Column
private String user_lname;
@Column
private String user_email;
@Column
private String user_address;
@Column
private String user_city;
@Column
private String user_state;
@Column
private long cell_num;
@OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="customer")
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private List<BankAccount> bacct;
```

BankAccount.java

```
  @Entity
@Table(name="USER_ACCOUNT")
public class BankAccount {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long acct_id;
@Column
private double balance;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private Customer customer;
```

And here is my hibernate config file as well(edited out the database connection info):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">adminone</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">adminpass</property>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect</property>
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
 <!--  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property> -->
<!--  <mapping resource="students.hbm.xml"></mapping> -->
<mapping class="com.revature.bank.POJO.Customer"></mapping>
<mapping class="com.revature.bank.POJO.BankAccount"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am using hibernate 3.0. Like i mentioned earlier, i have been trying to figure out the error but none of the online help seemed to fix it. As you can see, I'm not even trying to do anything to the database yet and it is throwing that exception. Any idea on why is this happening? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Are you aware that hibernate 3.0, is not jpa 2.0 If this is a legacy project, is this 3.0 or 3.x with hibernate-annoations

Comment: hibernate 3.6, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have JoinColumn on both sides. Just on the owner side, so remove it from the Customer class.

Customer.java:

```
@OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="customer")
private List<BankAccount> bacct;
```

BankAccount.java:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private Customer customer;
```

Comment: I did it but the same error keeps showing on the console. Could that be a problem with my database? or the hibernate config file?

Comment: I revised my pom file and I had a wrong dependency and it was giving me the wrong import, that is why it was giving me that issue